# I just want to add a .doc or an excel file in my app which can be opened by the viewer of my app in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Can anyone please give me the idea or the code of how to add an already existing `.doc` or `.excel` file in my  `first activity` of my app,so that it can be opened by the `viewer`

Comment: Can you please elaborate  'already existing .doc or .excel file in my 1 activity of my app',so that I can try to provide you the solution for whether you want to keep the file in assets and the open it or you want to open the file from sd card?

Comment: from assets, i wana open it